# How to test for NULL in SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

```
string query = 
  "select  User_name, User_Second_Choice 
   from tbl_User where User_Assigned_Project ='"+NULL+"'";
```

i try to select the rows to update so how can i change User_Assigned_Project = '"+NULL+"'";

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **IS NULL** not '= NULL'

```
select User_name, User_Second_Choice 
from tbl_User where User_Assigned_Project IS NULL
```